# How do I install portsf?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, audio

I am reading the Audio Programming Book by Richard Boulanger and I am at the point where the library portsf is presented and it is used in the examples. 
Portsf did not come with the DVD I found in the library of my university, but I have found it in this [link](https://github.com/daniel-murray/portsf).
However I have not found any resources on how to compile it in any platform.

I would like to know how to install it in OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only know how to install it in Linux, but since OSX uses a Unix like filesystem I'm sure it's similar. If you go into the portsf directory and type the "make" command you will get a libportsf.a file as a result. This file needs to go inside the directory that stores all of your archive library files. In Linux that directory is /usr/lib. Also the ieee80.h and portsf.h header files need to go inside the directory that stores all of your headers. I put them in /usr/include since that's where all my header files are located. 
Finally, to create an executable program you want to link it with the portsf library with the `-lportsf` option. For example: if I want to compile the sf2float.c program I type the following command:
`gcc sf2float.c -lportsf -lm -o sf2float`
that should create an executable file called sf2float. I have to use the -lm option because I'm including the math.h header file in sf2float.c
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey @jl.da I'm also using the Audio Programming book without the DVD. If you're interested in checking out what I've done so far you can follow me on [GitHub](https://github.com/umnum/Audio_Programs)

Comment: Hi @Michael, that is great! I am a little behind you, I just did the `sfpan` (but without the breakpoints). Did you do that program?

Comment: @jl.da, yes I did. You can browse through my entire commit history. If you look on my master branch on June 24 is when I first started working on sfpan.